# Apple Pages: How to entirely remove maring/padding of table

Tags: macos

I am using a table in Apple pages two have two columns. I want the text of the left column to be left-aligned with the text of the rest of the document.

Even if I set the text inset to 0pt and remove all borders, still the text of the left column is a bit more to the right.